# Oracle columns with lot of null data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table in Oracle like below. For different combination of ref_id_1 and ref_id_2, you will either have mapping_id_1 or mapping_id_2. if a value is there for mapping_id_1 then value for mapping_id_2 will be null and if mapping_id_2 has value then mapping_id_1 will be empty. mapping_id_1 and mapping_id_2 are foreign keys referred from another 2 tables respectively.

```
table: mapping
----------------------------------------------------------
| Id | ref_id_1 | ref_id_2 | mapping_id_1 | mapping_id_2 |
----------------------------------------------------------
  1      34         45         null            100
  1      34         45         null            101
  1      34         46         null            100
  1      34         45         100             null
  1      34         45         101             null
  1      34         46         101             null
```

Better design would be divide into 2 tables, one table with columns as ref_id_1 / ref_id_2 / mapping_id_1 and another one with columns as ref_id_1 / ref_id_2 / mapping_id_2.

Since it is a legacy table, I am unable to make changes to table. My question is, with above table if I create 2 indexes, one for ref_id_1 / ref_id_2 / mapping_id_1 and another one for ref_id_1 / ref_id_2 / mapping_id_2, assuming there are lot of null values in mapping_id_1 and mapping_id_2 will there be any performance impacts ? What is the drawback if I have more number nulls in a column like this case ?

Comment: Null don't impact perfomance and don't need space. so the design is ok

Comment: Is this an extremely large table where you need to painfully optimize as much as possible? The only thing I can think of, and this is a small thing, is that you could save a tiny amount of space by putting the columns that are most likely to be NULL at the end of the table. If MAPPING_ID_1 is NULL more often than MAPPING_ID_2, then move MAPPING_ID_1 to the last position. Oracle can save a tiny bit of space if the columns at the end of the table are all NULL, because each row stores the total size of the row in bytes, and it can infer the last columns are missing without storing any bytes.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @BobC: just wanted to check if this design is fine. In case in future if more mapping tables comes into picture in that case there could be mapping_id_3 / mapping_id_4 ... and if one mapping_id_*  column has value then rest of the mapping_id_* columns will have null values. So if I have to find a record with combination of id /ref_id_1 / ref_id_2 will there be any performance impacts ? Incase I create many indexes will have any issues ?